# XML Serialization Missing Some Elements

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

**following is the part of my xml serializing object.**

```
private decimal tOAMOUNTField;

public decimal TOAMOUNT
{
       get
       {
             return this.tOAMOUNTField;
       }
       set
       {
             this.tOAMOUNTField = value;
       }
}

XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClassObject));

var entity = new Myobject();
entity .TOAMOUNT = 2.22M;

using (StringWriter sww = new StringWriter())
{
      using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww))
      {
           //  sww.WriteLine(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>");
           xsSubmit.Serialize(writer , entity);
           output = sww.ToString();
      }
}
```

**above mention "ToAmount" Property is not serializing in XML**

Kindly point out the mistake because all other properties are serializing

Comment: Maybe `MyClassObject` is not same as `MyObject` and missing properties for serialization?

Comment: Let me save you some frustration. Copy all your XML, then go into a new class and click "Edit" at the top and "Paste Special" -> "Paste XML As Classes". This will correctly serialize the XML for you.

Comment: you complain about this - `<TOAMOUNT>2.22</TOAMOUNT>`?

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing a XmlSerializer object with type MyClassObject.

```
XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClassObject));
```

But are serializing a 'Myobject()' object.
Try changing it in:

```
XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Myobject));
```